# What is the proper order to apply modifiers after retopo?

Tags: animation, modifiers

i finished to retopo my character, now i need to know something important.

Now that i've reached here, i want to make my character look smooth with the subsurf, but... there's a thing. I want to animate my character, but wit the subsufr applied, it looks horrible when deforming it while animating. So, the other thing is that if i apply first the shrinkwrap, the mesh will lost it's smooth, it'll look in low poly and will lost a lot of details (so much work for nothing).

And now the question is this, what should i do now? it's the first step the correct one and i did a bad job while deforming with the armatures?
 ...Or it's the second one and i didn't do the applying thing correctly?

I have to mention that i applied the the mirror mod before these 2 mods, so it's important to know if i have to do that step in the end or.. i don't know.

[image]

EDIT:

This is how it looks with the shrinkwrap applied first.
[image]

I realized that when i apply the the wrap mod first and then i increase the subsurf by 2, the model looks 'squared'...

[image]
...and if leave it with only 1 subsurf, it'll lost a lot of important details.

Comment: Shrinkwrap first. Usually this modifier is applied. Then the stack is: Armature first, Subdivision last.

Comment: So, no matters if it looks 'awful'? i mean, it'll look like it doesn't have any subdivision on it? does it represent a problem?

Comment: imho the animation should work well with the subsurf disabled (or without any subsurf), or your (re)topology isn't good enough for that. when it will work well, a subsurf (applied or not) will make it look smoother...

Comment: I applied the shrinkwrap first, but now i've realized that the mesh looks awful with 2 subsurf, and if leave it with only 1 subsurf, i'll lost a lot of details.

Comment: After shrinkwrapping a low poly mesh to the sculpt, it is normal to [bake a normal map](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/blender_render/bake.html#normals) to simulate the small details on the lower poly mesh.

Comment: I've found that the subsurf looks like that because it's on "SIMPLE", but if it's switched to "CATMULL-CLARK" i'll look better and smooth.